# Issue validating multiple textfields with a single javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble validating multiple textfields with a single javascript function. The function only validates 2 textfields leaving the other, yet validation for all of them are well written. Please help!

````
function validate(form){
    var name = document.getElementById("SNameValue").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("SEmailValue").value;
    var emailvalid = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).([a-z]{2,5})(.[a-z]{2,5})$/;
    var phoneNum = document.getElementById("SPhoneValue").value;
    var phoneValid = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
    var suburb = document.getElementById("SsuburbValue");
    var message = document.getElementById("SMessageValue").value;

    //name validation
    if(name==""){
        alert("Enter your name, please");
        return false; 
            }
    //email validation
    if (email==""){
        alert("Enter your email address, please");
        return false;
            }           
    if(email.match(emailvalid)){
        return false;
        }   
    //phone number validation
    if(phoneNum==""){
        alert("Enter your phone number, please");
        return false; 
            }       
    if (phoneNum.match(phoneValid)){
        return false;
        } else{
       alert("Enter a valid phone number with 10 digits, please");
       return false;
     }
     //suburb validation
    if (suburb.selectedIndex==0){
        alert("Select your suburb, please");
        return false;
        }
    //message validation
    if(message==""){
        alert("Enter a message, please");
        return false;
        }
    //display everything    
    else{
        alert("Name: "+name+"\nEmail: "+email+"\nPhone number: "+phoneNum+"\nSuburb: "+suburb+"Message: "+message);
        return false;
        }
            return true;
} ```

HTML code:

``` <form onSubmit="return validate(this)" action="" method="Post">
        Name<br>
        <input type="text" id="SNameValue" placeholder="Enter Name"><br>
        Email<br>
        <input type="email" id="SEmailValue" placeholder="Enter Email"><br>
        Phone Number<br>
        <input type="tel" id="SPhoneValue" placeholder="Enter Phone number"><br>
        Suburb<br>
        <select name="suburbList" id="SsuburbValue">
          <option disabled selected value="">Select your suburb -- </option>
          <option value="Atlantic Seaboard">Atlantic Seaboard</option>
          <option value="Cape Flats">Cape Flats</option>
          <option value="City Bowl">City Bowl</option>
          <option value="Helderberg">Helderberg</option>
          <option value="NothernSuburb">NothernSuburb</option>
          <option value="South Peninsula">South Peninsula</option>
          <option value="Southern Suburb">Southern Suburb</option>
          <option value="West Coast">West Coast</option>
        </select><br>
        Message<br>
        <textarea rows="3" id="SMessageValue" placeholder="How can we help you"></textarea><br>
        <button class="button1" type="submit">Send me a Quote</button>
    </form>
````

I expect the function to verify and validate all the textfields, but it only validates the first 2 textfields.

Comment: `return false` exits the function immediately. Whether or not that's a source of confusion here, I don't know. **EDIT:** `if (email.match(emailvalid)) { return false; }` - looks like this line says "If the email is valid, return false.", though I'm basing that solely on your variable names. **EDIT2:** And then your phone number validation says *"If it's valid, return false. Otherwise, return false."*.

Comment: Sidenote: be careful with the e-mail validation regex. They are notoriously tricky to get right -- `"test@sd.mysite.com".match(emailvalid)` fails your test, for instance. See [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) for thorough discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like you need not condition in the regex validators,

```js
function validate(form){
    var name = document.getElementById("SNameValue").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("SEmailValue").value;
    var emailvalid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
    var phoneNum = document.getElementById("SPhoneValue").value;
    var phoneValid = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
    var suburb = document.getElementById("SsuburbValue");
    var message = document.getElementById("SMessageValue").value;
debugger;
    //name validation
    if(name==""){
        alert("Enter your name, please");
        return false; 
            }
    //email validation
    if (email==""){
        alert("Enter your email address, please");
        return false;
            }           
    if(!email.match(emailvalid)){
        return false;
        }   
  
    //phone number validation
    if(phoneNum==""){
        alert("Enter your phone number, please");
        return false; 
            }       
    if (!phoneNum.match(phoneValid)){
       alert("Enter a valid phone number with 10 digits, please");
       return false;
       
     }
     //suburb validation
    if (suburb.selectedIndex==0){
        alert("Select your suburb, please");
        return false;
        }
    //message validation
    if(message==""){
        alert("Enter a message, please");
        return false;
        }
    //display everything    
    else{
        alert("Name: "+name+"\nEmail: "+email+"\nPhone number: "+phoneNum+"\nSuburb: "+suburb+"Message: "+message);
        return false;
        }
            return true;
}
```

```html
 <form onSubmit="return validate(this)" action="" method="Post">
        Name<br>
        <input type="text" id="SNameValue" placeholder="Enter Name"><br>
        Email<br>
        <input type="email" id="SEmailValue" placeholder="Enter Email"><br>
        Phone Number<br>
        <input type="tel" id="SPhoneValue" placeholder="Enter Phone number"><br>
   
        Suburb<br>
        <select name="suburbList" id="SsuburbValue">
          <option disabled selected value="">Select your suburb -- </option>
          <option value="Atlantic Seaboard">Atlantic Seaboard</option>
          <option value="Cape Flats">Cape Flats</option>
          <option value="City Bowl">City Bowl</option>
          <option value="Helderberg">Helderberg</option>
          <option value="NothernSuburb">NothernSuburb</option>
          <option value="South Peninsula">South Peninsula</option>
          <option value="Southern Suburb">Southern Suburb</option>
          <option value="West Coast">West Coast</option>
        </select><br>
        Message<br>
        <textarea rows="3" id="SMessageValue" placeholder="How can we help you"></textarea><br>
        <button class="button1" type="submit">Send me a Quote</button>
    </form>
```